# how to differentiate the link in jquery?

Tags: jquery

when i click on the "Google" link in the example4,I am getting 2 alert messages.[It's showing alert3 message also].Please give a solution for this.i tried to differentiate the link in the example4 but no results.I am getting 2 alert messages.

what is wrong with this code.I am newbie in Jquery world.

Jquery code:

```
//Example 03 - Prevent Default Action of HTML Element 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Example 3 :: The default action of anchor element has been prevented using Jquery");
    });
});

    //Example 04 - Is Default Action Prevented of HTML Element
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a.checkaction").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("Example4 :: Is default action prevented of anchor <a>element :: "+event.isDefaultPrevented());
    });
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<!-- Jquery example 03 - Prevent default behavior of HTML element using Jquery -->
<h1 class="header">Example 3  - Prevent default behavior of HTML Element</h1>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>

<!-- Jquery example 04 - How to check whether the default action oh html is prevented or not using jquery -->
<h1 class="header">Example 4  - How to check whether the default action oh html is prevented or not</h1>
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="checkaction">Google</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below.

***Please note***, you only need to wrap your jQuery functions in one `$document.ready()` function. Also, you were receiving two pop-ups when you clicked example 4 because you set the jQuery selector to apply to all `anchors`. I added a `example-3` class to the `anchor` and revised the js to call it. I also used `return false;` to prevent the default action, versus your way. Cleaner and does the same thing in this case.

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Example 03 - Prevent Default Action of HTML Element 
    $("a.example-3").click(function(){
        alert("Example 3 :: The default action of anchor element has been prevented using Jquery");

        return false;
    });

    //Example 04 - Is Default Action Prevented of HTML Element
    $("a.checkaction").click(function(){
        alert("Example 4 :: The default action of anchor element has been prevented using Jquery");

        return false;
    )};
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Jquery example 03 - Prevent default behavior of HTML element using Jquery -->
<h1 class="header">Example 3  - Prevent default behavior of HTML Element</h1>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" class="example-3">Facebook</a>

<!-- Jquery example 04 - How to check whether the default action oh html is prevented or not using jquery -->
<h1 class="header">Example 4  - How to check whether the default action oh html is prevented or not</h1>
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="checkaction">Google</a>
```

Comment: In this instance, `return false;` prevents the default behaviour of the element. Commonly used when dealing with forms and jQuery. Same thing `preventDefault()` does essentially - but less code.

Comment: I thought his intention was to provide a default handler for all anchors, and then override that just for `.checkaction`.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the first handler to:

```
$("a:not(.checkaction)").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Example 3 :: The default action of anchor element has been prevented using Jquery");
});
```

Or you could combine both handlers:

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass("checkaction")) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: This is certainly the *much* cleaner route and the way I would have went about it if I was writing it myself. I kept it simple in my answer, as to avoid more concerns/questions from the OP (it's obvious he/she's starting out). +1

Answer (score 0):

Mate, the example 3 will hook a click function for all anchor elements in the page (facebook link and google link). Then, example 4 will hook ANOTHER click function for the google link...so the google link will be handled TWICE

Change the code to the following:

jQuery code:

```
//Example 03 - Prevent Default Action of HTML Element 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[name=fb]").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
        alert("Example 3 :: The default action of anchor element has been prevented using Jquery");
   });
});

//Example 04 - Is Default Action Prevented of HTML Element
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[name=gg]").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Example4 :: Is default action prevented of anchor <a>element ::       "+event.isDefaultPrevented());
});
});
```

Html code:

```
 <!-- Jquery example 03 - Prevent default behavior of HTML element using Jquery -->
<h1 class="header">Example 3  - Prevent default behavior of HTML Element</h1>
<a name="fb" href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>

<!-- Jquery example 04 - How to check whether the default action oh html is prevented or not using  jquery -->
<h1 class="header">Example 4  - How to check whether the default action oh html is prevented or not</h1>
<a name="gg" href="http://www.google.com" class="checkaction">Google</a>
```

Hope it makes sense

Leo

Comment: No harm from it, either.

Comment: Both are correct, but as Mike Barwick suggested a single document.ready function makes the code much cleaner and easier to maintain. I guess I just copied and pasted from the original post